# Jest maxWorkers option is not available in configuration file

Tags: jestjs

After I read through the docs. It seems to not have the option to set `maxWorkers` within the configuration files. I need to specify it in the cli.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: It's weird that some options are not listed in the config file docs but are useable (such as noStackTrace), but others are not (like maxWorkers).

Comment: which jest version you are using?

Comment: I'm using `jest@21.2.1`

Comment: Agreed, this is weird and unfortunate.

Answer (score 4):

Using `jest@26.1.0`, `npx jest --init` generates `maxWorkers` in `jest.config.js`. It's just not documented on the website.

```js
// ...

module.exports = {
  // ...

  // The maximum amount of workers used to run your tests. Can be specified as % or a number. E.g. maxWorkers: 10% will use 10% of your CPU amount + 1 as the maximum worker number. maxWorkers: 2 will use a maximum of 2 workers.
  // maxWorkers: "50%",

  // ...
};
```